# How to store a historical data of a calculated table during every refresh?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a a calculated table that gets refreshed during every refresh.

```
Weight = SUMMARIZE(filter(Sprints,Sprints[Delivery Name] in {"Retail Service","ATLAS DG"}),'Sprints'[Delivery Name],Sprints[Delivery Team],Sprints[Component],Sprints[Sprint Name],"Planned",[Planned Weight],"Mid",[Mid Weight],"End",[End Weight],"Total Sprint Score",[Total Sprint Score New])
```

I refresh my source dataset every week. Right now it just refreshes the values in the calculated table. I want to store last week's calculated table result set when I am doing this week refresh so that it will help me for my historical analysis. any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that is impossible. You should create a history table on the source database side.